# logging java class variables and its value dynamically

Tags: java, logging

How can I log class variables and its values dynamically?

Is there any way I can print variable names and its value dynamically by using only class object?

Like for example:

We pass `Person` class object and output is:

`Person:: age:10, name: abc`

something like that..

**EDIT:**

There are many classes. Any other solution other than Overriding `toString()` method? Can it all be dynamic. Like just passing the class object?

Comment: do you mean passing a "Class object" or simply means passing an "object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use something common in managed languages called [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).  Reflection allows you to know about the internals of the program at run-time.

In Java, you'll want to use the [getFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29) function on your class (or any other class).

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    for(Field field : this.getClass().getFields()) {
        System.out.println(field.getName() + ":" + field.get(this) + ",");
    }
}
```

This allows you to add new fields without the need for updating the`toString()` functions.

Comment: in your method `toString()` where does `person` object come from?

Comment: Sorry, edit error.  `person` should be `this`.  Fixed in my answer.

Comment: If this is what you're looking for, please set this as the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you override `toString` method and use Person class in `sysout` statements, its `toString` will be called internally. So override the toString method to print the object as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to override `Object.toString`.

Then you can add whatever descriptive field or class name reference you want in the `String` returned.

Then if you want to log your class dynamically to whatever logger you use (or simply, `System.out`) you can add an instance statement (possibly after the constructor executed) and log the `String` representation of your class there.

For instance:

```
public class Foo {

    private int blah;
    public Foo() {
        blah = 1;
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName().concat(": ").concat(String.valueOf(blah));
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
test.Foo: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `Person` class `toString` method.

```
public String toString(){
   return "Person:: age:"+age+", name: "+name;
}
```

Comment: you could follow `cmbasnett` answer